# How to handle multiple RecyclerViews in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to dynamically create and populate a list of CardView.
In my solution I create a MainRecyclerView with a MainAdapter. The ViewHolder in the MainAdapter is inflated by a CardView which contains a RecyclerView to manage the data inside each cardView.
My dubts are:

- Is this a good practice?
- What should contain the MainAdapter's List?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial [Create a Vertical Scroll and Horizontal Scroll App like Google Play Store](http://khmertechtrain.tk/index.php/2017/10/03/create-a-vertical-scroll-and-horizontal-scroll-app-like-google-play-store/).

Comment: That makes sense. Just put yourself out there and get ahead ;)